# How to integrate facebook login in flutter app

Tags: flutter, facebook, authentication

I'm trying to do facebook login in my app using `flutter_facebook_auth`. I did all configuration of android and ios. The problem is when i click on button it display the facebook login screen for few seconds then it hide. here is a method i'm calling on button click.

```
facebookSocialLogin() async { 
    final result = await FacebookAuth.instance
        .login(permissions: ["public_profile", "email"]);
    log("result   $result");
    if (result.status == LoginStatus.success) {
      final userData = await FacebookAuth.i.getUserData(
        fields: "email,name",
      );

      setState(() {
        _userData = userData;
      });
      log("_userData    $_userData");
    }
  }
```

please help how to fix this issue. I did the google login and it works fine too.

Comment: Did you add the keyhash in facebookconsole?

Comment: @SheetalGhori this problem is resolved now, thanks for your reply.